# Check a checkbox onclick without name or ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to come up with some code that I can execute onclick that will check a specific checkbox on a page. The checkbox does not have a unique name and does not have an ID. The only usable identifier is the value. 
I am limited to jQuery 1.4.2.
Nothing I have tried will work. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: _Nothing I have tried will work._ Well, what have you tried? Can you set up a demo, and include your markup and JS? Help us help you.

Comment: don't know if you of plnkr.co. but great place to put up your sample html and js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in earlier versions of jQuery:

```
$("input:checkbox[value='someVal']").attr("checked", "checked")
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2FpBJ).

Comment: Thank you! This is the first thing I have come across that worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously something you want to avoid doing but if the value is all you got, you'll have to traverse through the DOM for that input field where type=checkbox and where value is the value that you are looking for. What you can do is write a jQuery select for $('input[type=checkbox]') and there loop through all the checkboxes that have the value that you are looking for.

```
$checkbox = $('input[type=checkbox]')
$checkbox.each( function(k,v){
 if( $(v).attr('val') == somevalue ){ //using attr() instead of .val() since it's a checkbox
  $(v).attr('checked',true)
 }
}
```

So I checked out if you can just directly select it in jquery 1.4 using plunkr.

```
$("input:checkbox[value='someVal']").attr("checked", "checked")
```

And this works fine. Here's the plunk url to check out http://plnkr.co/edit/2sSjONghE5IfGlAvN2kk?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can refer it it by it's [index id](http://api.jquery.com/index/) or by [value](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][value=myvalue]").click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```